# Adding border-top to specific row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very simple table made with bootstrap and would like to add a border-top to a specific row, but for some reason, it's not showing up. This is what I have:

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>int</th>
                <th>rand</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>aaa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>xzcx</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border-top: 1px solid red;">
                <td>12</td>
                <td>scaaa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>ghghf</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eh1e20fs/)

Comment: Try putting the border on the `td` **inside** the required `tr`

Comment: [Worked for me](http://jsfiddle.net/eh1e20fs/5/)

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eh1e20fs/2/?

Comment: @Paulie_D , actually this code is fine just difficult to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `border-collapse: collapse;` to the table fixes this...

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to apply `border-top` in `td` not in `tr`:

```
<tr>
      <td style="border-top: 1px solid red;">12</td>
      <td style="border-top: 1px solid red;">scaaa</td>
</tr>
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eh1e20fs/4/)

Take a look here:

[Border conflict resolution](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you have is correct it is just very difficult to see. Try bumping the px size and it will be much more apparent. The style will be placed over both children; this is the best solution unless you want the border over a single cell.

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th >int</th>
            <th>rand</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="border-top: 10px solid red;">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>xzcx</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td >12</td>
            <td>scaaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>ghghf</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: border top]

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/HbEJHdoWEX)

Answer (score 0):

You must set the style to the `td` element. But, if you don't want to set twice the inline style you can set it by css only: http://jsfiddle.net/eh1e20fs/6/

```
.container table tbody tr:nth-child(3) td {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}

/* WHERE nth-child(n) refers to the number of the table row... */
```